# How do stop after an interesting line? Alternative for "Debug.Assert(false)"?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I can not explain it well:

```
    For Each sDir In sDirs

        Dim sFoldername As String = FolderNameFromPath(sDir)

        If Has(sFoldername, sFile) Or Has(sFile, sFoldername) Then
            'Here I want to make a breakpoint and inspect "sFile" and "sFoldername"
            'However, I don't know how
            'I can not use a breakpoint because there is line for that yet
            'The best I could come up with was this line:
            Debug.Assert(False)
        End If

    Next
```

As one can see in the below screenshot, without the additional line "Debug.Assert(false)" I wouldn't be able to inspect the values.
Alternatively I could have used "Dim i As Integer = 0" or something like that, but I would like to know if there is any official, smart way to do what I'm doing here.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You could use a Stop statement.

Comment: FWIW, I've always used `Debug.Assert(False)` for this type of thing.  I wasn't aware of `Stop`, but I might still prefer the assertion because it has an additional argument for giving a message (which I usually populate with the reason why I'm stopping).  Additionally, debug assertions don't do anything in a release build, which I would expect to be friendlier than `Stop` in most cases (the alternative would be to throw an exception).

Comment: @dbasnett Thanks, but I don't use Stop because I am afraid to forget about it and then have that in the compiled app.

Comment: @tmighty - I'd assume that you have code within the If, can't you use that to place your breakpoints?

Comment: @dbasnett Thanks for your comment. At that time, I don't have any code witin the If Then clause yet.